# Drupal Views Slideshow caption not resizing with browser

Tags: css, drupal

I have a drupal 7 views slide show with a caption on the bottom. The slideshow images are responsive when browser window is resized but the caption overflows on to the content area or moves up into the image. After a refresh it all works perfectly at the new window size.
Is there some css that can be applied to the caption which will keep it aligned to the image on resizing the browser.

```
    /*----------------------- Slideshow ------------------*/
.l-region--slideshow {

  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.views_slideshow_cycle_main_front_page_slideshow-block {
  position: relative;
}
.views-field-field-slide-caption .caption-enhance {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    // left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #015697;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 20px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    moz-opacity: 0.8;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity: 0.8;
    }

/* Make slideshow img responsive */

.views_slideshow_cycle_main {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.views_slideshow_cycle_main .views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto;
}
.views_slideshow_cycle_main .views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame-row {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto;
}
.views_slideshow_cycle_main .field-content {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.views_slideshow_cycle_main .field-content img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#views_slideshow_cycle_main_front_page_slideshow-block {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  border-bottom: double #ddd;

}

/*Make Caption Font Size Smaller for mobile ---------------------------*/
@media all and (max-width: 440px) {
  .views-field-field-slide-caption .caption-enhance {
    font-size: 75%;
    line-height: 1em;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just used FlexSlider Views Slideshow module instead of just a views slideshow and it all worked out responsively.